# Listview Sort by Column

Tags: c#, sorting, listview

I have an assignment about `ListView` sort by Column using C# Windows Form and the codes that I got from MSDN didn't work. Can anybody find out what's wrong with the codes? Everytime I click the `ListView` Column nothing happens.

Here's the code, I also added the items that will show in my `ListView`

```
private int sortColumn = -1;


    private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // Determine whether the column is the same as the last column clicked.
        if (e.Column != sortColumn)
        {
            // Set the sort column to the new column.
            sortColumn = e.Column;
            // Set the sort order to ascending by default.
            listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        else
        {
            // Determine what the last sort order was and change it.
            if (listView1.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
                listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
            else
                listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }

        // Call the sort method to manually sort.
        listView1.Sort();
        // Set the ListViewItemSorter property to a new ListViewItemComparer
        // object.
        this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(e.Column,
                                                          listView1.Sorting);
    }

    private void FillItems()
    {
        // Add items
        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("Nipun Tomar");
        item1.SubItems.Add("1");
        item1.SubItems.Add("10/11/2000");

        ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("First Last");
        item2.SubItems.Add("2");
        item2.SubItems.Add("12/12/2010");


        ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("User User");
        item3.SubItems.Add("3");
        item3.SubItems.Add("12/01/1800");


        ListViewItem item4 = new ListViewItem("Sample");
        item4.SubItems.Add("4");
        item4.SubItems.Add("05/30/1900");


        // Add the items to the ListView.
        listView1.Items.AddRange(
                                new ListViewItem[] {item1, item2, item3, item4});
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillItems();
    }


    public class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
    {

        private int col;
        private SortOrder order;
        public ListViewItemComparer()
        {
            col = 0;
            order = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        public ListViewItemComparer(int column, SortOrder order)
        {
            col = column;
            this.order = order;
        }
        public int Compare(object x, object y) 
        {
            int returnVal= -1;
            returnVal = String.Compare(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text,
                            ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text);
            // Determine whether the sort order is descending.
            if (order == SortOrder.Descending)
                // Invert the value returned by String.Compare.
                returnVal *= -1;
            return returnVal;
        }


    }
```

**Note: I added the columns in the design form.**

Here's what my assignment looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont have any columns in your list view. They are just items. thats why the event `listView1_ColumnClick` never fires. (also make sure you have added this event to your list view.)

Add this at first of your `Form1_Load` event to initialize columns.

```
// set view mode to see columns
listView1.View = View.Details;

// 100 is just a length of column. HorizontalAlignment.Left starts from left side    
listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Number", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Date", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

Now you see the columns which you can select them to sort items by that column.

Note that i just added 3 columns. so list view will show each item with 2 of their SubItems under columns by order.

As you requested to post the gif. Here is it :)

[image]

Comment: @Emman you have to select on columns not items. that event will only trigger when you for example click on `Name` then it will order by name. click on `Date` then it will order by date. do you want to something happen when you click on items?(edit: but in image i see them ordered by `Int`. it seems its working for you)

Comment: it's not ordered by `int`, in my code `FillItems` I entered it that way. Also I don't really get what your'e saying about columns because as you can see there's a `ColumnCLick` event that whenever I click a column it will sort ascending or descending. But my problem is I cant see where I have an error.

Comment: put a break point at first of your `ColumnCLick` event. start program in debug mode. click columns. see if it ever fires or not. if it fired and program stopped at break point then press `F11`. each time you press `F11` you will go one line forward. so check everything and try to find the problem. if the event never fired means you have not registered the event to the listview. @Emman

Comment: See this gif animated image how i do this. hope it helps. http://i.stack.imgur.com/IQlUz.gif if your problem is somewhere else then i cant help any more with given information.

Comment: WTF?! It really got to be the column click event. Thanks man! Next time I will check the properties more often.

Comment: I think you should post  the GIF in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You call `listView1.Sort()`before setting the comparer:  `this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = ...`

Just invert the two lines.

Also, note that you are using `string.Compare` for all columns, which, I think, it's not what you want for column 3 (date)

[Edit]:
Just realized now the setting the value for ListviewItemSorter cause the LV to sort: your code seems to work even without calling `listView1.Sort()`

Problem must be somewhere else. Try with debugger setting breakpoints...

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void lvw_ColumnClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {

        ListViewColumnSorter sorter = new ListViewColumnSorter();
        sorter.SortColumn = e.Column;
        sorter.Order = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;
        lvw.ListViewItemSorter =sorter;
        lvw.Sort();
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: what is ListViewColumnSorter?!!

Comment: Agreed - this does not compile as is. Some info about the type?